# /proc/net/tcp results filter and converter

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, io, ip-address

Being unable to easily read the output of /proc/net/tcp I made a small C# console app that modifies the output to be in decimal notation instead of the standard hexadecimal, show the corresponding enum states of the state code and added the ability to filter out remote addresses. With the ability to further tweak to your own needs/add custom messages.

By default /proc/net/tcp returns the result in the following format:

```
 2: 6400A8C0:A21F 6400A8C0:ADC1 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000 10296        0 802001 1 0000000000000000 25 4 0 21 -1
```

After running it through the assistant the output changes to:

```
2:  192.168.0.100:41503  192.168.0.100:44481  ESTABLISHED 00000000:00000000 00:00000000   00000000   10296        0 802001   1 0000000000000000  25   4   0  21  -1
```

The following code ([github view](https://github.com/RemyRM/proc-net-tcp-assistant/blob/07fc6ecac3f84bdf144e763c55f07d72dc8713fd/ProcNetTcpConverter.cs)) works when run in the adb shell with any connected Android device:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

class ProcNetTcpConverter
{
    //These values can either be hardcoded, or left empty. If left empty the programm will ask for the user to input manually.
    static string filePath = @"";
    internal static string[] remoteIPFilter = new string[] { "" };

    static readonly string header = string.Format("{0, 5} {1, 20} {2, 20} {3, 12} {4, 5} {5} {6} {7, 5} {8, 10} {9, 7} {10, 8} {11}", "sl", "local_address", "rem_address", "state", "tx_queue", "rx_queue", "tr", "tm->when", "retrnsmt", "uid", "timeout", "inode");
    static readonly string ipRegex = @"[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.SetWindowSize(220, 50);

                if (filePath.Equals(""))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please specify file path");
                    filePath = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                if (remoteIPFilter.Length == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IPv4 Filters (seperated by space, leave blank if none):");
                    remoteIPFilter = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                    if (remoteIPFilter[0] != "")
                    {
                        IPCheck();
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press escape or ^c to pause");
                do
                {
                    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {
                        RunBatch();
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

                Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to resume");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the given ip is valid. 
    /// Checks ip recursively after entering new IP.
    /// </summary>
    static void IPCheck()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < remoteIPFilter.Length; i++)
        {
            var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(remoteIPFilter[i], ipRegex, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (!match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid ipv4 address, please re-enter, or leave blank to continue.", remoteIPFilter[i]);
                remoteIPFilter[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                if (remoteIPFilter[i] != "")
                {
                    IPCheck();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Run a batch script that checks for all open TCP connections on a connected device.
    /// </summary>
    static void RunBatch()
    {
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    FileName = filePath
                }
        };

        process.Start();
        string rawResult = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        ReplaceHexNotation(rawResult);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Repalce the ip address + port that is in hex notation with an ip address + port that is in decimal notation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rawResult"></param>
    static void ReplaceHexNotation(string rawResult)
    {
        string[] splitResults = rawResult.Trim().Split('\n');

        Console.WriteLine("\n" + splitResults[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < splitResults.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(header);
            }

            if (i > 2)
            {
                TCPResult result = new TCPResult(splitResults[i]);
                string message = result.GetMessage();
                if (message != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert an ip address + port (format: 00AABB11:CD23) from hex notation to decimal notation.
    /// Implementation taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355163/8628766
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">Hex "ip:port" to convert</param>
    /// <returns>Input ip as decimal string</returns>
    static internal string ConvertFromInput(string input)
    {
        string[] ipPart = input.Split(':');
        var ip = new IPAddress(long.Parse(ipPart[0], NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)).ToString();
        var port = long.Parse(ipPart[1], NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier).ToString();
        return ip + ":" + port;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the index of a character's n'th occurance
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">Input string</param>
    /// <param name="t">Character to check</param>
    /// <param name="n">Occurance index</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal static int GetNthIndex(string s, char t, int n)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == t)
            {
                count++;
                if (count == n)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("GetNthIndex Exception: Index was out of range.");
    }
}

class TCPResult
{
    private readonly string tcpResultMessage;
    enum TcpStates
    {
        ESTABLISHED = 1,
        SYN_SENT,
        SYN_RECV,
        FIN_WAIT1,
        FIN_WAIT2,
        TIME_WAIT,
        CLOSE,
        CLOSE_WAIT,
        LAST_ACK,
        LISTEN,
        CLOSING,
        NEW_SYN_RECV,

        TCP_MAX_STATES
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Recreate the Tcp result message so we can re-format it with the new ip format
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rawInput">input string</param>
    internal TCPResult(string rawInput)
    {
        rawInput = rawInput.Trim();
        List<string> inputList = rawInput.Split(' ').ToList();
        inputList.RemoveAll(o => o.Equals(""));

        string sl = inputList[0];
        string local_address = ProcNetTcpConverter.ConvertFromInput(inputList[1]);
        string rem_address = ProcNetTcpConverter.ConvertFromInput(inputList[2]);
        TcpStates st = ((TcpStates)Convert.ToInt32(inputList[3], 16));
        string tx_queue = inputList[4].Substring(ProcNetTcpConverter.GetNthIndex(inputList[4], ':', 1) - 8, 8);
        string rx_queue = inputList[4].Substring(ProcNetTcpConverter.GetNthIndex(inputList[4], ':', 1) + 1, 8);
        string tr = inputList[5].Substring(ProcNetTcpConverter.GetNthIndex(inputList[5], ':', 1) - 2, 2);
        string tmWhen = inputList[5].Substring(ProcNetTcpConverter.GetNthIndex(inputList[5], ':', 1) + 1, 8);
        string retrnsmt = inputList[6];
        string uid = inputList[7];
        string timeout = inputList[8];
        string inode = "";

        //iNode doens't always have 8 parameters. Sometimes it only has 3
        if (inputList.Count > 12)
        {
            inode = string.Format("{0, 6} {1, 3} {2, 16} {3, 3} {4, 3} {5, 3} {6, 3} {7,3} ", inputList[9], inputList[10], inputList[11], inputList[12], inputList[13], inputList[14], inputList[15], inputList[16]);
        }
        else
        {
            inode = string.Format("{0, 6} {1, 3} {2, 16} {3, 3} {4, 3} {5, 3} {6, 3} {7,3} ", inputList[9], inputList[10], inputList[11], "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1");
        }

        //return if the remote address is in the filter array
        if (ProcNetTcpConverter.remoteIPFilter.Contains(rem_address.Substring(0, rem_address.IndexOf(':'))))
        {
            return;
        }

        tcpResultMessage = string.Format("{0, 5} {1, 20} {2, 20} {3, 12} {4, 5}:{5} {6}:{7, 5} {8, 10} {9, 7} {10, 8} {11}", sl, local_address, rem_address, st.ToString(), tx_queue, rx_queue, tr, tmWhen, retrnsmt, uid, timeout, inode);

        if (Convert.ToInt32(tx_queue, 16) > 0 && st == TcpStates.ESTABLISHED)//Indicates this is the current active transmissiting connection
        {
            tcpResultMessage += " <= Active transmitting connection";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(rx_queue, 16) > 0 && st == TcpStates.ESTABLISHED)//Indicates this is the current active receiving connection
        {
            tcpResultMessage += " <= Active receiving connection";
        }
    }

    internal string GetMessage()
    {
        return tcpResultMessage;
    }
}
```

Running the following batch script:

```
@echo off
echo %time%
adb.exe shell cat /proc/net/tcp
```

The program works. But I'm interested to learn if i'm using any bad practises, or doing other things wrong. Especially the `TCPResults` class/constructor could be implemented a lot better I think, but unable to come up with how myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Regular expressions

You might [consider compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969158/when-not-to-use-regexoptions-compiled) your regular expressions.

```
ipRegex = new Regex(@"[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"
        , RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

---

#### Path normalization

> ```
> Console.WriteLine("Please specify file path");
> filePath = Console.ReadLine();
> ```

-> append the following method to have some leverage on user input.

```
filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(filePath )
```

---

#### New lines

> `rawResult.Trim().Split('\n');`

Are you sure to use `\n`? Perhaps this is fine. Maybe consider using `Environment.NewLine` instead. It depends how this tool encodes new lines.

---

#### Seperation of concerns

Method `ReplaceHexNotation` performs both tokenizing and outputting to the console. You should extract algorithms from output for better usability and maintainability.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> inputList = rawInput.Split(' ').ToList();
inputList.RemoveAll(o => o.Equals(""));
```

Instead, you can do:

```
string[] inputList = rawInput.Split(' ', System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```